# compare list of tuples with eachother then use information to create a new list

Tags: python

so I have a list containing tuples, each tuple has a code in the zero index of it and a name in the first index

```
[('s530', 'smythe'), ('s530', 'smith'), ('d120', 'davies'), ('d120', 'davis')]
```

essentially what i'm trying to do is compare each tuple in list with a nested loop and determine which names have the same code. then use this information to construct a line of output and then store it into a new list

so for instance from the example list of tuples i would want to create a list of strings like so

```
['smythe and smith have the same code','davies and davis have the same code']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
a=[('s530', 'smythe'), ('s530', 'smith'), ('d120', 'davies'), ('d120', 'davis')]

def process(n):
    ret = []
    for i in n:
        for j in n:
            if i==j:
                break
            if i[0]==j[0]:
                ret.append(f"{i[1]} has same code as {j[1]}")
    
    return ret


print(process(a))
```

this is a simple one
it simply uses nested loops twice and ignores the same thing

Comment: that's quite inefficient if the list of tuples is big